# What is $ in nasm assembly language?

Tags: assembly, nasm

This is my assembly level code ...

```
section .text
global _start
_start  mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, mesg
        mov edx, size
        int 0x80
exit:   mov eax, 1
        int 0x80
section .data
mesg    db      'KingKong',0xa
size    equ     $-mesg
```

Output:

```
root@bt:~/Arena# nasm -f elf a.asm -o a.o
root@bt:~/Arena# ld -o out a.o
root@bt:~/Arena# ./out 
KingKong
```

What is the $ in the line `size    equ     $-mesg`. Some one please explain the about the `$` symbol used ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` indicates the 'current location' of the assembler as it goes along.  In this case it's used to store the length of the `mesg` string.

```
size equ $-msg
```

Says "make a label `size` and set it equal to the current location minus the location of the `mesg` label".  Since the 'current location' is one past the end of the string "KingKong\n", `size` is set to that length (9 characters).

From the [documentation](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.09/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5):

> NASM supports two special tokens in expressions, allowing calculations to involve the current assembly position: the `$` and `$$` tokens. `$` evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using `JMP $`. `$$` evaluates to the beginning of the current section; so you can tell how far into the section you are by using `($-$$)`.